# Running rspec as part of a program, rather than as a dedicated test suite

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing some code to manage virtual machine instances, and the syntax for RSpec is just about perfect to allow me to define "rules" for new instances. Think something along the lines of:

```
@vm.memory.should be >= 4096
```

Readable and easy to understand for others. Perfect.

The problem is that I can't find a way to invoke rspec *from within* my program and get the status of the tests back. Right now, I'm using a very hackish method - dumping the `@vm` object out to a temp file along with necessary includes, and then using `Kernel#system` to launch rspec as a command line process which includes that tempfile, and checking the exit code to tell whether the tests all passed or not.

Is it possible to:

- Run rspec from within another program using pure Ruby
- ..and get the pass/fail result?

Comment: See the last answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986319/execute-rspec-from-ruby

Comment: Perfect! This wasn't coming up in the search. Going to ask for a dupeclose on this one.