# Get Rspec test data in JSON format

Tags: ruby, json, rspec

How can I get the data from my Rspec tests in JSON format? like, how many tests failed etc.

I know that I can get it if I run Rspec from ruby, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412793/805156)
I'll just paste the code here for convenience.

```
run(paths)
  # runs rspec tests from ruby
  # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412793/805156

  config = RSpec.configuration

  formatter = RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter.new(config.output_stream)

  # create reporter with json formatter
  reporter =  RSpec::Core::Reporter.new(config)
  config.instance_variable_set(:@reporter, reporter)

  # internal hack
  # api may not be stable, make sure lock down Rspec version
  loader = config.send(:formatter_loader)
  notifications = loader.send(:notifications_for, RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter)

  reporter.register_listener(formatter, *notifications)

  RSpec::Core::Runner.run(paths)

  formatter.output_hash

end
```

Is there a way to write this json output to a file whenever Rspec test suite runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this just involves running with a specific formatter you can just run

```
rspec --format json > output.json
```